# How can I draw a map and write on it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, formatting

I need to have a real map like the one attached, and I do some writing on it ?? 
Any suggestions please 
[image]

Comment: Is the map a simple image that already exists?

Comment: @Tom: Most likely it is a screen shot of some map application, e.g. some `.png` or `.jpg` file.

Comment: If the map is an already existing file of `.jpg`, `.pdf` or `.png` format, use `TikZ` to overprint it with  math content. If it is not existing, use `Tikz` as well ;-)

Comment: Yeah. I got it from academic paper

Comment: See also https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/119641/how-can-i-get-a-real-map-and-write-on-it (possible "duplicate")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that you have the map as a picture (`.jpg`, `.png`, ...).

I am using the example image from the `graphicx` package. To illustrate the use.

You can use Ti*k*Z to draw on the image and add lines. I have added two points and a connecting line. The points are arbitrarily named (here p0 and p1). You can add many points and connect them with the a line (just add `-- (p3)` and so forth to the existing one).

```
% with ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2628796

\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for example images

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={fill=white, inner sep=1mm}]

    % styles
    \tikzstyle{myLabel}=[draw=black, circle, fill=white]
    \tikzstyle{myLine}=[draw=blue,  double]

    \draw (0,0) node[inner sep=0] {\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}};

    % nodes
    \node[myLabel,label={above:$(l,t)_2^D$}] (p0) at (1,2) {} ;
    \node[myLabel,label={right:$(l,t)_3^D$}] (p1) at (3,1) {} ;

    % lines
    \path[myLine] (p0) -- (p1) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

this example will look like this:

[image: example image]

With a picture of a "real" map (and a photo by Lorenzo Cafaro from [Pexels](https://www.pexels.com/de-de/foto/abenteuer-ausflug-beratung-draussen-240834/?utm_content=attributionCopyText&utm_medium=referral&utm_source=pexels)) it will look like this:

[image: map with text on it]